# How deploy and install web app on Digital Signage Tizen os Samsung QM43R

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Im frontend developer and I must develop web app for Samsung's digital signage monitor - QM43R. I investigated it and found that I can make it with HTML, CSS and JS. But I don't know how to deploy and install my app. There is no information about deployment. OS is Tizen, but it's not a smart TV, it's digital signage monitor.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Comment: 2022 and I still think this Digital Signage from Samsung has a very poor documentation. Were you able to do it, Chingiz?